# How to calculate training loss on selected subsample predictions

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, backpropagation, loss-function

I am training a deep learning multi-target tracking model on video sequence.
The video frames are extracted and annotated at `1fps`. 
To utilize smoother temporal coherence, I have extracted the intermediate 24 frames between every `2` annotated frames. Now, I have all the frames extracted at `25fps` but the ground truth labels are available only at the interval of `25` frames initially annotated.

I want to train a deep learning model by providing all the smooth `25fps` frames during forward pass, but during *backprops*, I want to calculate and optimize the loss only for the annotated `1fps` frames.

Any hint on how I should go about this? Especially when my `mini-batch size` is less than `25`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One useful thing I am doing so far, is to have -1 label for the un-annotated frames and skip them when computing loss. This may be sub-optimal but works, anyone with a better idea?